# Xcode: Send button backward (not to back) using code

Tags: xcode

Anyone knows how to send a button backward through code? 
I am animating a button moving backward when being selected, thus sometimes another button will overlap the one that goes backward. 
I was only able to find the code to send a button (entirely) to the back, but that's not what I am looking for, since this would make my button end up behind my background image.

This one: 
[[btnTarget_Portrait superview] sendSubviewToBack:btnTarget_Portrait];

Thanks for help!

Kr, Kim

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: why not just set it's alpha to 0?

```
btnTarget_Portrait.alpha = 0.0f;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for offering this solution. I'm sorry that my explanation wasn't too clear; in my animation, there are five buttons in a dock. When one button is clicked, the button will shove backward. But because I want to use depth, the buttons at the utter left and right side will slightly move towards the middle, which makes that they should disappear 'partially' behind the button next to them. The wrong button is on top at the moment, which makes that the effect isn't right. Please let me know if I'm not clear enough in my explanations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code seems true if you share more information and code snippet we can help but you can use various solution;

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:<#(UIView *)#>];// which component brings to front
```

OR

```
btnTarget_Portrait.hidden = YES / btnTarget_Portrait.hidden = NO (depends on situation)
```

Comment: Well, I guess that I could add more code snippets (like the animations I added), but I don't know if that would be useful. I found the solution for my app by modifying the button-"hierarchy" in interface builder. But in case you would need a more extended hierarchy where each button would partially be hidden, I guess there could be a different solution (since there are different levels between "hiding" or bringing buttons to back/front, but actually 'arranging' a hierarchy of button objects in the canvas). Thanks for your reply!